# Proto is unable to find the proto files

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, proto

I have a protofile dataresponse.proto and when i am trying to generate its java object class. it is throwing exception saying "Missing input file" although the proto file is placed in the directory provided in command.
Command tried `protoc --proto_path=E:/protofile/dataresponse.proto --java_out=E:/protofile`

Comment: can you try using backslash ? e.g. protoc E:\protofile\*.proto --java_out=E:\protofile

Comment: I tried. but it did not worked.